# How to check if array is empty or not and return value inside foreach in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have below data,

What i want to do is, i need to check `values[] array` in each object,

**if it is empty then return true**, else if `values[] array` has some record, it will return false.

i have created function for this, but it is reuturning false everytime.

if it is true thn i want to hide table. Table are multiple not single one, so if values arrayis empty thn only want to hide particular table.

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "MYTEAM-Consume-TEAM-SETUP-ADMIN"
        ]
      },
      "values": []
    },
    {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "TEAM1"
        ]
      },
      "values": [
          {
          "value": "red",
          "label": "dd"
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "Test"
        ]
      },
      "values": []
    },
  ]
}
```

Code

```
hideContextTable(rows) {
    const data = rows;
    if (data.records) {
      data.records.forEach(function (record) {
        if (record.values.length === 0) {
          return true;
        } 
      });
    }
    return false;
  }


deleteAllContextData(data) {
    const tbl = this.hideContextTable(data);
    console.log(tbl,"tbl");
    if (tbl) {
      this.showContextTables = false;
    }
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the length of returned data from `filter` function.

```js
data = {
  "records": [
    {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "MYTEAM-Consume-TEAM-SETUP-ADMIN"
        ]
      },
      "values": []
    },
    {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "TEAM1"
        ]
      },
      "values": [
          {
          "value": "red",
          "label": "dd"
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "Test"
        ]
      },
      "values": []
    },
  ]
};
function hideContextTable(data) {
  const result = data.records.filter(record => record.values.length);
  const flag = result.length ? true : false;
  console.log(flag)
}

hideContextTable(data);
```

Comment: While your answer solves the problem, it does not provide insight on why the existing code did not work. I suggest adding a small description of what went wrong, and how to fix it before suggesting a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`return` in the higher order function of `forEach` will not cause flow to leave the `hideContextTable` function. You should use a variable that is accessible from outside that function and set it if the condition is met, then return that variable at the end of the function.

```js
const rows = {
  "records": [
    {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "MYTEAM-Consume-TEAM-SETUP-ADMIN"
        ]
      },
      "values": []
    },
    {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "TEAM1"
        ]
      },
      "values": [
          {
          "value": "red",
          "label": "dd"
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "context": {
        "team": [
          "Test"
        ]
      },
      "values": []
    },
  ]
}


function hideContextTable(rows) {
    let isEmpty = false;
    const data = rows;
    if (data.records && data.records.values) {
      data.records.forEach(function (record) {
        if (record.values.length === 0) {
          isEmpty = true;
          return;  // this is a higher order function
                   // meaning: it won't leave the context of hideContextTable
        } 
      });
    }
    return isEmpty;
  }


const test = hideContextTable(rows);

console.log(test);
```